# Integer sum of powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-theorem

> Prove that for integers $a,b$ number : $(a+\frac{1}{2})^n+(b+\frac{1}{2})^n$ is integer for finitely many integers $n$.

I tried to use Binomial theorem but I didn't find any interesting.

Comment: Do you have to find finitely many integers it holds for or prove that it **only** holds for finitely many integers?

Comment: Did you try searching the site? This is likely a dupe.

Comment: I have to prove that it only holds for finitely many integers.

Comment: Note that your numbers satisfy $$c_n=(a+b+1)c_{n-1}-\frac {4ab+2a+2b+1}4c_{n-2}$$

Comment: @Aryabhata: Undoubtedly a duplicate, I remember solving it. But *finding* is another matter.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: True. But Alex has done it!